# How to see if current user exists in people and groups field, using ecma/client-object-model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-online

I have a list which has two fields. (Title,EditPermission). The EditPermission is "people and group" field. I can use the following code to compare the current user with the spuser in that field

```
    var cName = _currentUser.get_title(); 
    var admins = currentItem.get_item('Admins');
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < admins.length; ii++) {
                        var admin = admins[ii].get_lookupValue();
                        if (admin == cName) {

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
```

What I need here is suggestion to get the spgroup info while traversing and then see if user exists inside it or not.

Another point, Is there any better way to do it, like may be using CAMl query? that will result the list rows that has "Me" in "EditPermission" column.

Comment: var condition = '<Where><Or><Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\"> <FieldRef Name=\"PEOPLE_GROUPS_COLUMN_NAME\"/></Membership><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"PEOPLE_GROUPS_COLUMN_NAME\"></FieldRef><Value Type=\"Integer\"><UserID/></Value></Eq></Or></Where>';
This Query will return the rows belonging to current user, either assigned directly or in group

Comment: Further Reading at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544234.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From OP's comment:

```
var condition = '<Where><Or><Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\"> <FieldRef Name=\"PEOPLE_GROUPS_COLUMN_NAME\"/></Membership><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"PEOPLE_GROUPS_COLUMN_NAME\"></FieldRef><Value Type=\"Integer\"><UserID/></Value></Eq></Or></Where>';
```

This Query will return the rows belonging to current user, either assigned directly or in group.

Further Reading at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544234.aspx