# highlight row on current user exists in a people or group column in a list view

Tags: javascript, user, jslink, client-side-rendering, membership

I need to highlight a row in a list view, if current user is selected in a people or group field in this view, directly, or using SharePoint group.
I really would like to do this using JS. Is this possible?

I know how to highlight a row, I only need the checking part.

I found this topic:

[How to see if current user exists in people and groups field, using ecma/client-object-model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40673/how-to-see-if-current-user-exists-in-people-and-groups-field-using-ecma-client)

But I really didn't get how to implement this query in a script.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that the fastest way to get current user for on-premises 2013 is _spPageContextInfo.userId.
Now i need to somehow compare this to the view field, which is:
Multi-value people or group field.
Is it possible with CSR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the below script. I didn't really like the criteria i used to separate users form groups, but i didn't find any other simple option.

**UPDATE**
Updated the script and corrected errors. You can read further in my [blog](https://journeymblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/16/highlight-row-if-current-user-exists-in-a-people-or-group-column-in-a-list-view-as-user-or-spgroup-member/)

```
//BELOW CODE SETS ROW COLOR IF USER IS SELECTED IN A int_x002e_lrn_x002e_members DIRECTLY OR THROUGH SPGROUP//
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var SPfield = "int_x002e_lrn_x002e_members" //YOU CAN SET PEOPLE AND GROUPS FIELD HARE
    var RowColor = "#ada" //YOU CAN SET ROW COLOR HERE
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/CurrentUser/Groups?$select=Id,Title';
    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    var usergroupsids=[];
    var result=null;
    result = $.ajax({url : requestUri,contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",headers : requestHeaders,global: false,async:false,success : function(data) {return data;}})
    for (var i = 0; i < result.responseJSON.d.results.length; i++){usergroupsids.push(result.responseJSON.d.results[i].Id);}
    //alert(usergroupsids); //FOR TESTING
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
      for (var e=0;e<rows[i][SPfield].length;e++)
      {
        var isGroup = rows[i][SPfield][e].department == "";
        if (isGroup)
        {
            if (($.inArray(rows[i][SPfield][e].id, usergroupsids)) != -1)
            {
                var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
                tr.style.backgroundColor = RowColor; 
                //alert('Current User is in a group' + rows[i][SPfield][e].title) //FOR TESTING
            }
        //alert('Element ' + e + ' ' + rows[i][SPfield][e].title + ' is a Group') //FOR TESTING
        }
        else
        {
            if (_spPageContextInfo.userId == rows[i][SPfield][e].id) 
        {
            var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
            tr.style.backgroundColor = RowColor; //YOU CAN SET ROW COLOR HERE
            //alert('Element ' + e + ' ' + rows[i][SPfield][e].title + ' is a User') //FOR TESTING      
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check JSLINK for same. Using JSLINK we can change rendering of listview.

For more detail check below reference link.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: I know how to change rendering, i dunno how to get current user and compare him to the people or group field value.

Comment: You can get current user ID by _spPagecontextinfo.Userid and compare it people picker column value.

Comment: ``document.querySelectorAll("[href*='userdisp.aspx?ID="+_spPageContextInfo.userId+"']")`` gets you the A tags, you can walk up the DOM from there

Comment: Thanks Sam, _spPageContextInfo.userId is working great, though it seems case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes..It's case sensitive and please make answer as rihht.